# Why would someone offer an Asheira to Hashem?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There's a verse in Tehillim which says "Asheira LaHashem Ki Gamal Alai".

Just because there's a camel on me I'm going to burn an Avoda Zara as a sacrifice?

Moreover, when I think it was Gidon *did* burn an Asheira to Hashem, he had no camel on him, so when did this Asheira burning ceremony take place?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Hey! I had some Purim Torah lined up for this verse! No fair!

Comment: @Yez, if you have a specific answer, you can ask a moderator to unlock the question.